# Ubuntu Wubi 12.04 LTS won't mount

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 32-bit as a Wubi install, but I get this:

> An error occurred while mounting `/tmp`. I can choose to skip mounting or repair manually.

I certainly don't know what to do. Could someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

can you please unplug the internet cable and make sure you run wubi installer as administrator

Comment: I tried this . nothing changed except for an error occurred while mounting /. no tmp

Comment: btw, i shrinked a hdrive volume and made a separate partition to install ubuntu

Comment: @JustasWait if you made a separate partition, then you don't want to use Wubi. It installs to a virtual partition, a [loop device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device), which is a single file. You need to boot from an Ubuntu DVD/USB to install properly.

Comment: yes you can use livecd and check partition with gparted

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the wubi.exe installer for the same version of iso image.

You should also try the following.
If it is windows 7, you need tools like daemon tools, which could mount the iso image. In Windows 8, this feature is already present.

Mount the image, and then, run the downloaded wubi.exe installer. Also no need of usb drive or cd.